# Remove sales reorder from right sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I need a little help again.
I been able to remove several stuff from the right sidebar, using local.xml, with no problem.

I want to remove the sales reorder the same way but it's not working. Can anyone give me a clue please?

Partial local.xml above.

```
    <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.permanent.callout</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.poll</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.reports.product.viewed</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.cart.sidebar</name>
            </action>
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>right.sales.reorder.sidebar</name>
            </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: use this <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"></remove>

Comment: @LearningMagento I already done that. Your complete answer with the info to remove almost everything ;)

Comment: Anyway it use some one while searching same question

Comment: None of the options works after i copied to the server. I am forgetting something?

Comment: check your local.xml it should be under your custom theme

Comment: @LearningMagento It's there. I checked. Already flush the cache. Is there something I forgot to change on admin maybe?

Comment: None of the option in the sense. can you plz post your url

Comment: can't do it. Still closed in development stage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this

**Removing the shopping cart at the right side**

```
<remove name=”right.cart_sidebar”/>
```

**Removing the standard banners**

```
<remove name=”right.permanent.callout”/>
<remove name=”left.permanent.callout”/>
```

**Removing recently viewed products**

```
<remove name=”left.reports.product.viewed”/>
<remove name=”right.reports.product.viewed”/>
```

**Removing the PayPal logo**

```
<remove name=”paypal.partner.right.logo”/>
```

**Remove the compare sidebar**

```
<remove name=”catalog.compare.sidebar”/>
```

**Remove compared products bar**

```
<remove name=”right.reports.product.compared”/>
```

**Remove reorder sidebar**

```
<remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"></remove>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>reorder</name></action>
</reference>
```

OR

```
<remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case ,you need to use `customer_logged_in handler` for remove  reorder from right side bar.Because of  this ***handler only call whenever customer is loggedin***  and ***reorder block is called when custom is loggedin***

As the ***sales reorder block alias name*** is `reorder` then using this you can remove.

**So.you can try this:**

```
<customer_logged_in>
          <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>reorder</name></action>
        </reference>

</customer_logged_in>
```

Comment: that's true but we will not use the reorder block in any case so I will remove it in any case @amit .  Is there place where I can see the alias names of  blocks?

Comment: suppose a block code define at layout like ` <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />`  then `state_renderers` called as alias name of block because of under  as="state_renderers"

Answer (score 0):

```
  <reference name="right">

            <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar" />
</reference>
```