# Disable Recently Ordered / Reorder Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can i disable Recently order or Reorder block in magento 2?

In css i can hide the block "block block-reorder" by display:none;

But I want to fully disable it.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85743/remove-sales-reorder-from-right-sidebar

Comment: it's for magento 1., i'm looking for magento 2.

Comment: It will be same for magento 2 as well

Answer (score 26):

Create default.xml in your module or theme's view/layout folder and paste the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  After making the change, you need to clear the layout cache and page cache.

Answer (score 3):

You can create new deafult.xml in your custom module and write below code to remove recent order block from Left sidebar

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../../htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
         <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
     </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Actually only `<referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>`is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Refer below steps to enable or disable **customer reorder** in Magento 2

- On the Admin panel, click `Stores`. In the `Settings` section, select `Configuration`.
- Select `Sales` under `Sales` in the panel on the left
- Open the `Reorder` section
- In the `Allow Reorder` field, select Yes to allow reorders and select No to disable reorders.
- When complete, click `Save`.

Comment: This had no effect for me on Magento 2.2.9.  I changed the setting to "No" but the re-order sidebar block did not go away.

Comment: @jdhildeb I don't have Magento 2.2.9 installed, I have checked in 2.3.2 it's working.

Comment: I have also 2.3.2 but it not working...